# Are these sets closed and convex?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let $S_j \subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$, for every $1\leq j \leq n$.

Then is the set define by following constraints convex closed and bounded (assume it is not empty)?

$$ \sum_{k\in S_j} x_{k}=1,\space \forall 1\leq j\leq n$$
$$x_i\geq 0,\space \forall i$$

Comment: How are $j$ and $i$ related?

Comment: Have you tried graphing this set in dimensions 2 and 3? You should be able to see how boundedness and convexity arise from this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited the problem and now the number of i and j both equal to n.

Comment: Thanks @EricStucky. Good idea! I will try graphing it in low dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For closedness, I don't think you can avoid doing some heavy work, but it's possible that the heavy work has already been done for you. For example, if you know that addition is a continuous function then you can recognize this set as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function. If you know that every affine subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is closed, then you can recognize the set as the intersection of $n+1$ appropriate subspaces.

Otherwise, you have a couple options. You can go about proving one these things, in which case you have gotten seriously involved in a proof of a much more general technique, which may appeal to you. Or if you're really only interested in this set you can always start from the definition. Suppose that $x\in\mathbb R^m$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $y$ in the set with $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$. It might help to observe that every ball in $\mathbb R^m$ contains a box (an $m$-cell), and vice versa, because the algebraic conditions on boxes are less infuriating than those on balls :)